# Gitlab CI OpenSearch Service Issues

Tags: gitlab-ci, opensearch

I am using OpenSearch for my project. I have a docker-compose file that builds it all locally and runs my tests, which works fine. I have created a gitlab-ci.yaml file that tries to replicate some of this on a scaled down version.

```
  services:
    - name: mysql:latest
      alias: mysql      
    - name: opensearchproject/opensearch:latest
      alias: opensearch-node1
      command: ["bash", "-c", "env 'discovery.type=single-node' 'cluster.name=opensearch' ./opensearch-docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

I assume the url would be https://opensearch-node1:9200. This is what sits in my .env.example file that gets renamed to .env for my Laravel application and test.

When my application runs the test, it gives me the following error:

`No alive nodes found in your cluster`

What could be causing this?

I have tried changing the cluster.name, adding in an ip address etc. A curl call to `curl -sS http://opensearch:9200/_cat/health` shows that it is healthy, but that same config fails with the info in the .env file.